# Where to put system parameters in Xamarin Android project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Where should we put system values, like backend url, that are different between dev, test and production?

Our build pipeline produces one apk at the moment. Would it be possible to have the release pipeline change these values inside the apk file? Or do we need to build different apk's for test and prod?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup diffrent buildconfigurations:
[image]

and then you can simply set conditions in the code

```
#if PROD
        // API & End points
        private const string apiSubscriptionKey = "asdf543";
        private const string apiBaseUrl = "base0.com";
#elif TEST
        // API & End points
        private const string apiSubscriptionKey = "asdf123";
        private const string apiBaseUrl = "base.com";
#else
        // API & End points
        private const string apiSubscriptionKey = "asdf1234";
        private const string apiBaseUrl = "base2.com";
#endif
```